# Passing *args or **kwargs into threading.Thread()

Tags: python, multithreading

Using the threading library, I am attempting to pass down a variety of args/keyword args into the threading function. There are three different situations. Each one consists of a function ran prior to the threading function, which passes down the options to the threading function to tell it what function to call for the threading, and the arguments. In some situations, there will be keyword arguments, in some arguments, and in some, none. Here is the sample code of the threading function:

```
def create_some_threads(my_target, *my_args, **my_keyword_args):
        for DeviceName in Devices:
            device_ip = Devices[DeviceName]['mgmt_ip']
            my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_target, args=(device_ip, DeviceName, *my_args, **my_keyword_args))
            my_thread.start()
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_target, args=(device_ip, DeviceName, *args, **kwargs))
                                                                                ^                                                                
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the function where I call in the *my_args:

```
pingable_devices = {}
unpingable_devices = {}
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    print("\n[+] Progress:\n")
    pbar = tqdm(total=100)
    my_args = (pingable_devices, unpingable_devices, pbar, limbo)
    my_target = ping_em_all
    create_some_threads(my_target, *my_args)
```

The problem is, for each function I use prior to calling the threading function, there are a different set of arguments/keyword arguments that I will call. I attempted to make this a function on its own, but if I can't run it something like this, then I may have to explore other avenues.

Edit: This first problem was solved by unutbu, but now I have encountered a second problem. It seems the function called by the threading function is not recognizing the variables passed into threading, my_args. Error is below:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "Automatelab.py", line 157, in ping_em_all
    ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', '-w', '2', '-q', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
NameError: global name 'device_ip' is not defined
```

Here is the ping_em_all function:

```
def ping_em_all(*my_args, **my_keyword_args):
    """.rstrip is needed for the ip as .readline adds a \n to
    the lines' text"""
    if "Linux" in platform.system():
        ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', '-w', '2', '-q', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
    #Darwin is Mac OSX
    elif "Darwin" in platform.system():
        ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', '-t', '2', '-q', '-n', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
        """Subprocess for Cygwin still not supported"""
    else:
    #Only other would be Windows
        ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '2', '-w', '2', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

The target is [called with](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96b06aefe23521b61e4e9cdd44f5d30b00c7eb95/Lib/threading.py#L882):

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

Therefore, you could use:

```
def create_some_threads(my_target, *my_args, **my_keyword_args):
    for DeviceName in Devices:
        device_ip = Devices[DeviceName]['mgmt_ip']
        my_args = (device_ip, DeviceName,) + my_args
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_target, 
                                     args=my_args, kwargs=my_keyword_args))
        my_thread.start()
```

---

When you define you define a function with `*my_args` or `**my_keyword_args` in its call signature, note that `my_args` becomes a tuple inside the body of that function, and `my_keyword_args` becomes a dict.

```
my_args = (device_ip, DeviceName,) + my_args
```

simply concatenates two more values to the front of the `my_args` tuple.

---

The error message

```
NameError: global name 'device_ip' is not defined
```

is saying that the variable name `device_ip` has not been defined [in a scope that is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/190597) at the point where the `NameError` occurred. A look at the `ping_em_all` function shows that that's true:

```
def ping_em_all(*my_args, **my_keyword_args):
    """.rstrip is needed for the ip as .readline adds a \n to
    the lines' text"""
    if "Linux" in platform.system():
        ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', '-w', '2', '-q', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
    ...
```

`device_ip` is the first value in `my_args`:

```
my_args = (device_ip, DeviceName,) + my_args
```

Therefore, change `ping_em_all` to

```
def ping_em_all(*my_args, **my_keyword_args):
    """.rstrip is needed for the ip as .readline adds a \n to
    the lines' text"""
    device_ip, DeviceName, my_args = my_args    #<-- This defines device_ip
    if "Linux" in platform.system():
        ping_reply = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', '-w', '2', '-q', device_ip.rstrip('\n')],stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
    ...
```

to unpack values from the `my_args` tuple and give them variable names.

Comment: So that did work, but now I have a separate problem. All variables in my_args are not recognized by the target function. See above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible issues I see.

In this line:

```
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_target, args=(device_ip, DeviceName, *my_args, **my_keyword_args))
```

You don't need the asterisks in front of `*my_args` and `**my_keyword_args` The asterisk goes in the function parameters but inside of the function you can just refer to them as `my_args` or `my_keyword_args`. Secondly, for the `args` parameter, you can remove the `my_keyword_args` from that and instead put it at the end. Here's a basic format to help clarify:

```
import threading

def start_thread(function_name, *args, **kwargs):
    t = threading.Thread(target=function_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def this_and_that(input_data, started=False, finished=False):
    for i in names_list:
        if started is True and finished is False:
            print(i, started, finished)
        elif started is True and finished is True:
            print(i, started, finished)
        else:
            print(i, started, finished)

n = ['Steve','Smith']

start_thread(this_and_that, n, started=True, finished=True)
```

Output looks like this:

```
Steve True True
Smith True True
```